# Dcrypt a password without asking for master password

Tags: security, session, encryption, passwords

I know there are other posts regarding password storage and encryption but my question is slightly different.

I am working on a password manager website, for fun. And was wondering how secure this idea I had was.

So obviously each password the user stores is encrypted using AES-256 with their master password as the key and a randomly generated salt. Also the master password is encrypted using Bcrypt, but before hand it is hashed some 100,000 times using something like whirlpool, to increase strain when trying to login.

If a user decides he doesn't want to enter his password every time he/she requests a password for a site the program cannot decrypt the password and autofill because the master password is required to decrypt the stored passwords.

One idea I had was to store the password in the users current session, but that's not really a good idea because I am trying to make this assuming the attacker has already breached my server and is downloading the database and snooping around.

Another though was to use the 100,000 time hashed password as the key for the AES-256 encryption and store that hash in the session. That's better then storing it in plain text, but it still lets the attacker be able to decrypt the stored passwords if he/she can get the information from the session.

Are there better ways around this, or is this a lost battle of hope the attacker doesn't get in when I'm logged in?

Comment: use a temp token instead of passing around hashes or passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want full security, the passwords should be in stored in such a way that not even the server can decrypt them without user input, and thus the master key would only ever be stored clientside.

Since you don't want it stored in the session, you could store it in a cookie client side, but the bottom line is, if an intruder has breached your server and can modify its code, in order for the site to be functional, they by definition must be able to get the passwords if the decryption of the passwords happens server side.

So if you were willing to, you could write a javascript/client side application that would receive the AES encrypted strings for a given user, and would decrypt it client side with the users entered Master Password. The issue with this is you will have to have a secondary piece of information before you give a user his encrypted passwords, or you would have to be willing to give everyone, everyone elses encrypted passwords if they request it. There is an additional hidden complexity here, if your intruder is able to change the code on the server, they could in theory change it from running client side to running server side and thus get those decrypted passwords, or they could modify the client side javascript to make an AJAX call with the decrypted passwords.

> Also the master password is encrypted using Bcrypt, but before hand it is hashed some 100,000 times using something like whirlpool, to increase strain when trying to login

There is no need for that, just increase Bcrypt's strength parameter to increase time when they try to login. Bcrypt has key stretching built in.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have to choose between security and convenience.

One can make it harder to get at the key, e.g. using hardware based solutions, but finally at some point your application must be able to retrieve the stored passwords in plain text. If the attacker has full control over the server, nothing prevents him to do exactly the same steps.

For a maximum of security, not even the server must be able to decrypt the stored passwords, and that's only possible if the key remains on client side. What you could do is writing an app for the client, and use the server only to store the encrypted password repository.

BTW, the BCrypt algorithm already does key-stretching, therefore it is not necessary to add additional rounds of hashing. The better solution in this case is, to increase the cost factor.